# Inspect time delay for the app to launch in Monkey tool

Tags: android, android-layout, stress-testing, monkeyrunner, monkey

I'm trying to find out the time-lapsed for the app to launch using the Moneky tool for a specific package. I'm not familiar with what kind of command line could give the time delay the app takes to launch. What if I want to run the same command multiple times to check the difference in time when the app is at **hot startup and then when the app at cold startup**. Here is the link I looked for [here.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time).
I run the default command line but didn't understand the meaning of **elapsed time=5584ms**.

```
adb shell monkey -p com.facebook.katana -v 1000> secondTest.txt
```

Here are some the outputs of the secondTest.txt:

```
 Events injected: 1000
 :Sending rotation degree=0, persist=false
 :Dropped: keys=0 pointers=0 trackballs=0 flips=0 rotations=0
  ## Network stats: elapsed time=5584ms (0ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 5584ms not connected)
 // Monkey finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `monkey` to inject 1000 random events, so the elapsed time reported is the time needed to process those events. You could inject only 1 and see how long it takes, however there's a better way, check the logcat for a line like

```
ActivityManager: Displayed com.facebook.katana/.StartupTiming: +2s325ms
```

This value represents the amount of time elapsed between launching the process and finishing drawing the corresponding activity on the screen.

Comment: Thank you, I know this method before. I'm trying to make it with the Moneky stress testing tool. I think injecting a random one event might not consider calling the app directly, it might do different events, like checking the volume sound, etc.

Comment: From the docs: "Here is a more typical command line, which **will launch your application** and send 500 pseudo-random events to it: `$ adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500`", so sending 1, will launch your app and send the event.